# Deixar o HTML.DropDownList() com o estilo do Bootstrap?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho uma `DropDownList`na minha `View` e apesar de ter a classe `form-control` a lista não fica com o estilo do `Bootstrap`.

Como posso editar a forma como o `DropDownList` constrói as listas?

```
@Html.DropDownList("countriesDiretorySelect",
              new SelectList(ViewBag.Countries as System.Collections.IEnumerable,
              "NumKeyId",
              "VarResourceLevelName"),
              new { id = "countriesDiretorySelect", @class = "form-control " })
```

Como tenho o site todo baseado em `Bootstrap`, não quero deixar escapar este elemento. Tenho o projeto em `MVC4`.

Answer (score -1):

Aparentemente está tudo certo. Sugiro uma outra construção para manipular melhor sua *DropDown*:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.countriesDiretorySelect,
              ((IEnumerable<Country>)ViewBag.Countries).Select(c => new SelectListItem {
                  Value = c.NumKeyId.ToString(),
                  Text = c.VarResourceLevelName,
                  Selected = (Model != null) && (Model.countriesDirectorySelect == c.NumKeyId)
              }), "Selecione...", new { id = "countriesDiretorySelect", @class = "form-control" })
```